# How does this url pattern cause an infinite checkup in Django?

Tags: django, django-urls

I think it's doing infinite check up because it Django never arrives at `build_history` view function.

```
# CodeBundles
url(r"^cb/create/$", 'codebundle_create', name="codebundle_create"),
url(r"^cb/details/(?P<cbid>\w+)/$", 'script', name="codebundle_details"),
url(r"^cb/(?P<cbid>\w+)$", 'codebundle_browser', name="codebundle_browser"),
url(r"^cb/(?P<cbid>\w+)/(?P<path>\w+)$", 'codebundle_browser', name="codebundle_browser"),

#### url(r"^cb/(?P<cbid>\w+)/(?P<path>(.|\W|\w)+)/delete/$", "deletefile", name="deletefile"), 

url(r"^cb/newfile/$",   'codebundle_newfile',   name="codebundle_newfile"),
url(r"^cb/newfolder/$", 'codebundle_newfolder', name="codebundle_newfolder"),
url(r"^cb/build_history/(?P<cbid>\w+)/$", 'codebundle_build_history', name="codebundle_build_history"),
url(r"^cb/run_history/(?P<cbid>\w+)/$", 'codebundle_run_history', name="codebundle_run_history"),
```

Notice the guy gets commented out is the murderer.

I get `502 Bad Gateway` when I enable that url pattern, and I don't understand why.

Django main url: http://192.168.1.138/natrium/

I go to `codebundle_browser`, either urls will work fine

```
http://192.168.1.138/natrium/cb/12343
http://192.168.1.138/natrium/cb/12343/./ABC
```

Once I get into `codebundle_browser` page, I can click on `build_history`, and then I end up with `502 Bad Gateway`.

So `deletefile` url pattern is causing an infinite checkup? But `build_history` is a different url pattern, shouldn't Django be smart enough to go to `build_history` if the request url is

```
http://192.168.1.138/natrium/cb/build_history/12343/
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use `.|\W|\w` which basically means: any symbol or not letter or letter. Maybe this causes some kind of deep recursion in regexp?

Comment: The delete needs to match cases (path) like `./directory`, `/hello`, `abc.py`, etc, so anything like `.  - _ 1 A z ` might appear. Not a really good regx writer. I think precedence will work (move delete to the bottom). Is there a better regx?  Thanks. I mean I don't quite understand why `cb/build_history` doesn't matched. Clearly, `cb/build_history/` is not `cb/1234` (and 1234 is a captured value) and futhermore, I am calling `{% url codebundle_build_history cbid %}`.... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you're not using regexp properly.

Here you can find documentation about regexps in python: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Rules like this:

```
url(r"^cb/(?P<cbid>\w+)$", 'codebundle_browser', name="codebundle_browser"),
url(r"^cb/newfile/$",   'codebundle_newfile',   name="codebundle_newfile"),
```

Basically overlap, because `\w+` can mean `newfile`. (it probably doesn't overlap here because of extra `/` but django uses convention to append `/` to end of url)

For ids (numbers) you should use `(?P<cbid>\d+)` that only matches digits (any digits one or more times).
For anything between you can use `.+` (any symbol one or more times)

I also recommend you to follow RESTful URI design goals http://redrata.com/restful-uri-design/

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, `cbid` is not plain digits. It's a hashed value mix with digits and characters, so we are forced to use `\w+`. So with the killer expression, it's pretty dummy way of saying `matches kleen plus of dot, non-character, or character`...

Comment: you are right about using `.+` I guess when I read `.` I thought it wouldn't match non-alphabetical characters. It works now. Thanks for pointing out mistakes.